# SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate mailgun

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, mailgun

I have installed mailgun on my local machine.

I am using `localhost:8000` to run my laravel project. I tried to send the message and I received this message

```
RequestException in Client.php line 136: 
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Can anyone explain how it is solved?

Comment: Mailgun is a web based email service, how have you "installed it on your local machine"?

Comment: Using composer installed on the project. And tried sending it using localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `curl` from `https://curl.haxx.se/download.html`

Download win64 version then extract.

copy `ca-bundle.crt` to `/apache/bin/`

Then open `php/php.ini` and edit line

```
curl.cainfo = "/path/to/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/bin/ca-bundle.crt"
```

Restart server